# Table rows getting refreshed automatically

Tags: sapui5

I have created a Table in SAPUI5 and added rows to this table using `oTable.addItem(oRows)`. It worked perfectly. But suddenly when I scroll or click somewhere in the screen, refresh icon (processing circle) appears in table row automatically.

code:

```
function addData(results, oTable, add) { //Here results table has my data which is added to table
  for ( var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var oEntry = {};
    oEntry.SAP__Origin = results[i].SAP__Origin;
    oEntry.Sbname = results[i].Sbname;
    oEntry.Fname = results[i].Fname;
    oEntry.Lname = results[i].Lname;
    oEntry.Stdate = results[i].Stdate;
    oEntry.Sttime = results[i].Sttime;
    oEntry.Endate = results[i].Endate;
    oEntry.Entime = results[i].Entime;
    oEntry.Status = results[i].Status;
    oEntry.Tzone = results[i].Tzone;

    var oTemplate = new sap.m.ColumnListItem(
        {
          cells : [
              new sap.m.Text({
                text : oEntry.SAP__Origin
              }),
              new sap.m.Text({
                text : oEntry.Sbname
              }),
              new sap.m.Text({
                text : oEntry.Fname
              }),
              new sap.m.Text({
                text : oEntry.Lname
              }),
              new sap.m.Text({
                text : z_cof_subs.util.Formatter
                    .date1(oEntry.Stdate)
              }),
              new sap.m.Text({
                text : z_cof_subs.util.Formatter.time(
                    oEntry.Sttime, oEntry.Tzone)
              }),
              new sap.m.Text({
                text : z_cof_subs.util.Formatter
                    .date1(oEntry.Endate)
              }),
              new sap.m.Text({
                text : z_cof_subs.util.Formatter.time(
                    oEntry.Entime, oEntry.Tzone)
              }),
              new sap.m.Switch(
                  {
                    state : z_cof_subs.util.Formatter
                        .check(oEntry.Status),


                  }) ]
        }

    );

    if (add == 'X') {
      oTable.addItem(oTemplate);
    } 
  }
};
```

I don't know why refresh icon is appearing. Any faced this issue before?

Comment: Do you set any setBusy methods? Is there any data being loaded when you click? Without showing your code it's impossible to tell what's going on.

Comment: I did not use any setBusy() for this table. No data is loaded. Only refresh (circle loading) icon is being displayed repeatedly as if it is updating the table. BUt there is no data to update.

Comment: Guys,
Thanks for you help. I solved it. I was using property growingScrollToLoad="true" while creating table. Hence, when I scroll down this refresh was happening.

Comment: So, there *was* data being updated after all...